# jQuery .load() function not working with DataTables?

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I am attempting to use Datatables with an external html Table. The below code works just fine:

```
<table id="myTable" class="table table-striped" >  
  <thead>  
    <tr>  
      <th>ENO</th>  
      <th>EMPName</th>  
      <th>Country</th>  
      <th>Salary</th>  
    </tr>  
  </thead>  
  <tbody>  
    <tr>  
      <td>001</td>  
      <td>Anusha</td>  
      <td>India</td>  
      <td>10000</td>  
    </tr>   
  </tbody>  
</table>
```

However, if I do so like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="includedContent"></div>
</div>
```

With this as the script:

```
$(function(){
  $("#includedContent").load("bigtableofdata.html");
});
```

The system no longer works. I cannot seem to figure this out, and I'm wondering if I need to specially format it in some way for this to work. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to initialize the plugin in complete callback of `load()`

```
$("#includedContent").load("bigtableofdata.html", function(){
  /// new html exists now
  $('#myTable').DataTable(/*options*/)
});
```

Note there are also built in ajax options configurations in DataTables API that are a more common approach to ajax loading the data

Comment: Thank you very much, would you be able to point me in the direction of where to find these Ajax options? I'm new to all this. Thanks.

Comment: This approach *will* work. The datatables documentation has ajax examples you can follow. All the examples show runnable code